# Using implicit variable in function literal

Tags: kotlin

I started reading Kotlin course book. I stopped on function literals. Here I have a code:

```
val printMessage = { message: String -> println(message) }
printMessage("hello")
printMessage("world")
```

Then I have an information that I can omit parameter type:

```
{ message -> println(message) }
```

And now I have next step:

"In fact, Kotlin has a neater trick. If there is only a single parameter and the type can beinferred, then the compiler will allow us to omit the parameter completely. In this case, itmakes the implicit variable it available:

```
{println(it)}
```

And now after using this code I get an error "unresolved reference: it" and "too many arguments for public operator fun invoke(): ??? defined in kotlin.Function()":

```
val printMessage = {println(it)}
printMessage("print something")
```

My question is how to use implicit variable in single paramenter function literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter), specifically where it says:

> If the compiler can figure the signature out itself, it is allowed not
>   to declare the only parameter and to omit `->`. The parameter will be
>   implicitly declared under the name `it`.

In your case, the compiler (at least up to current version 1.3.31) can't figure the signature out itself:

```
val printMessage = {println(it)}
```

But if you give your `printMessage` variable an explicit type, it will work:

```
val printMessage: (String) -> Unit = { println(it) }
```

Comment: I guess your book is "Programming Kotlin" (page 121) by  Stephen Samuel and Stefan Bocutiu (Packt Publishing). It's not wrong, but could have been clearer that the compiler needs to be able to figure out the signature.

Answer (score 3):

You always need to provide all information about all generic parameters. If you want to omit it, it needs to be inferable from some other part of the code. The only information you provide though is that you want `printMessage` to be a lambda. So it assumes it to be of type `()->Unit`. This is because you don't declare a parameter for the lambda itself. The implicit parameter `it` is therefore not usable.

```
val printMessage = { it: String -> println(it) }
val printMessage: (String)->Unit = { println(it) }
```

Simply put: If you're inside a lambda with one parameter, the implicit `it` can be used as this parameters name, but a reference named `it` within the body of the lambda doesn't declare the single parameter.

Comment: Which one is more often used and more readable? I just started learning and for me first line looks better. Or does it just depend on personal preference?

Comment: I only use lambdas as parameter for which you have to declare the type explicitly. In this case I'd actually declare a local function: `fun printMessage(value: String) = println(value)`. This also makes the usage clear for the reader.